# Print json output in Ansible and store in a list?

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

Ansible playbook:

```
---
- task:-
  - code goes here

  - name: Trying to get instance Private IP from ASG
    ec2_instance_facts:
      instance_ids: 
         - "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ INSTANCE_IDS_FROM_ASG }}"    
    register: instance_ids_result

  - set_fact:
      msg: "{{ instance_ids_result | json_query('results[*].instances[*].network_interfaces[*].private_ip_address') }} "

  - debug: var=msg
```

I have the output as follows:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "172.31.144.74"
        ],
        [
            "172.31.147.69"
        ]
    ]
}
```

But, I would need the output in a list as `["172.31.144.74", "172.31.147.69"]` or `"172.31.147.69" "172.31.147.69"`.
What is the best way to print it that way?

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten your list using the filter

```
  - set_fact:
  msg: "{{ instance_ids_result | json_query('results[*].instances[*].network_interfaces[*].private_ip_address') | flatten }} "
```

Comment: Also, I found this, helped by one of my colleague.
 
```msg: "{{ instance_ids_result | json_query('results[] | [*].instances[] | [*].network_interfaces[] | [*].private_ip_address') | join(',') }}```